# What is Bacon.js equivalent to Rx.JS' withLatestFrom()?

Tags: rxjs, bacon.js

I'm trying to get use of **atomic updates** Bacon.js offers so have to rewrite Rx.JS code at some places of my app to Bacon.js, but can't figure out yet how can I implement **withLatestFrom()** with Bacon.js?

In such a way that, for example, when user clicks, some code executes with latest value from `$serverResponses` stream, but when server responses, that code (click handler) should not execute.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sampledBy. It has inverse argument ordering compared to withLatestFrom, but does the same thing.